# When editing text in editext it loses its focus and the keyboard show out so fast

Tags: android-layout

My code works fine before I changed my layout from relative into linear layout in my xm file.What could be the cause of this? How can i fix this? I already tried some of I have researched here but nothing worked.Some says there something to put on manifest but it didn't work for me.Can you please help me out of this.

**useritemdetail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/Item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:text="Item"
android:textSize="15dp" />

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/label"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/Item"
  android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
  android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/Quantity"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/label"
 android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:text="Quantity"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/inputQty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/Quantity"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp" >
<requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/uom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/inputQty"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:text="UOM"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/inputUom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/uom"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/Amount"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/inputUom"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:text="Amount"
android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/inputAmt"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/Amount"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:inputType="number"
android:textSize="12sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/TotalAmount"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/inputAmt"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:text="Total Amount"
android:textSize="15dp" /> 

<TextView
android:id="@+id/inputTamt"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/TotalAmount"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can't getting what exactly you want, this xml should work proper. have you given any extra thing in your xml?? like "android:windowSoftInputMode" or other??